# jquery scroll not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

I have a website with a div with overflow scroll so the height is fixed. 
I tried to integrate scroll by clicking the blue buttons but it isn't working well. It makes strange things.
http://cepidesigns.com.ar/no-cache/cronosREG/

This is my javascript code:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    $('.boton').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).find('.boton').addClass('clicked');

 if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var $target = $(this.hash);
  $target = $target.length && $target
  || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if ($target.length) {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top+270;
    console.log($target.offset().top);
    if(targetOffset==0)
      return false;
    $('.main')
    .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
   return false;
  }
 }  
});
```

Can you help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :)

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
  $('.boton').removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).find('.boton').addClass('clicked');

  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
  && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var $target = $(this.hash);
    $target = $target.length && $target
    || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if ($target.length) {
      var targetOffset = $target.offset().top+270;
      if(targetOffset==0)
        return false;

      $('.main')
        .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset-$('a[name="home"]').offset().top}, 1000);
     return false;
    }
  }
});
```